# How do I extract a vector from a column-major matrix in C?

Tags: c, matlab, matrix

Coming from a MATLAB background, I have often used the fancy matrix manipulation commands such as `vec = matrix(:,1)` for extracting, e.g., the first column of `matrix` as a vector.

Porting some code to C with the need to interface it with FORTRAN and MATLAB now has me store matrices in single-dimensional arrays with column-major order.

So basically, I am using the macro

```
#define SUB2IND_2D(s1, s2, i1, i2) (s1)*(i2) + (i1)
```

and the loops

```
for(size_t r=0; r<ROWS; ++r)
{
    for(size_t c=0; c<COLS; ++c)
    {
        size_t index = SUB2IND_2D(ROWS,COLS,r,c);
        // do something with matrix[index] here
    }
}
```

in order to access the respective matrix. Now, my question is: How can I efficiently extract a column or row vector from `matrix` within this framework in C, just like I would do in MATLAB using matrix(:,1) or matrix(1,:) or similar?

Comment: What about writing some function `getRow(...)` that uses the code you posted but for fixed `r`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's say you want to extract a column number 2 give it a name ex_col:

```
int ex_col[];

for (size_t x=0; x<ROWS; x++)
{
size_t index = SUB2IND_2D(ROWS, COLS, x, 2); // fix column to 2 and extract all rows
ex_col[x] = matrix[index];
}
```

Now you can generalize it to a function

Comment: you're welcome ;) it happens to me all the time also don't worry

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what your trying to achieve.  vec(r,c) will give you access to a specific element.  Otherwise you answered your own question. vec(:,r) will extract your rows and vec(c,:) will extract your columns when you run your loop.

Comment: I know how to use the colon command in MATLAB. My question was pointing at: How do I do the same in C, if matrices are stored in column-major arrays?

Comment: I misunderstood your question.